# Mat-selection-list with close icon baseed on objects

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

Am trying to create a UI like below based on the following data

```
data ={Parent1:[child1,child2],Parent2:[child3,child4]}
```

[image]

Is it possible to make this UI from mat-selection-list?

OR any other one available

And also need to know how to iterate above data structure through ***ngFor**

Expecting a solution

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using keyvalue pipe provided by Angular directly? It is definitely possible to create this UI from mat-selection-list. What should be the features? Should all checkboxes be independent from each other or should a click on the parent checkbock toggle all child checkboxes? In the second case it could be benefitial to use MatTableModule insted.

Comment: i need to show "X" button instead of checkbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following template to render data as shown in UI:
The parent entry is not a list-option, therefore anything wanted can be inserted on the right hand side of the list item.

```
<mat-selection-list>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of (data | keyvalue)">
    <mat-list-item>
      {{item.key}}
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let child of item.value">
      {{child}}
    </mat-list-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-selection-list>
```